# MV6 EF6 database first possible?

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I needed to know if there is a way to use entity framework 6 database first with MVC6?If so, can someone provide the steps for the same?

Comment: Shouldn't have any problems - https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html

Answer (score 2):

#### EF 6 Database First

Using EF 6.1.3, there is a "Database First" option that will generate a `.edmx` file that contains all of the model info (storage, conceptual, mapping).  To access this is VS 2015, **Project -> Add New Item**, then choose **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**; on the first screen of the Entity Data Model Wizard, choose **EF Designer from Database**.  When you complete the wizard, it will generate a `.edmx` file and add it to your project.  You can use the visual designer/diagram GUI to make changes to your models, or you can edit the XML (`.edmx` file) directly.  There are some things that are not supported in the designer, so you very well may end up editing XML at some point.  The other point worth mentioning is that if your database changes later on, there is an **Update Model from Database** option (when viewing the diagram, right click in an empty area inside the diagram and you should see a context menu with the Update Model from Database option).  However, this will only update the Storage model in the `.edmx` file; you are still responsible for updating your Conceptual model, and the mapping between the two (using the GUI, or editing the XML).

I was interested in using a Database First approach too, and spent many hours fiddling with `.emdx` files to try to create workflow I was happy with, but ultimately abandoned that approach.  The primary reason I gave up is that I wanted a fully automated way to update the models after database changes; with the database first approach, the only option is to make manual changes in the GUI after a database update.  There is a command line tool named `edmgen.exe` that supposedly will generate a `.edmx` file automatically, and at first glance looks like a solution for automation.  However, `edmgen.exe` is missing some key features that are only available in the GUI.  Specifically, the command line tool doesn't support stored procs; the only way to generate a `.edmx` file containing stored procs is via the GUI, and the only way to avoid hand-editing the Conceptual model and mapping in the GUI is to delete the `.edmx` file and regenerate from scratch every time.  I couldn't come up with an automated way to do that, so I gave up.  Also, the next version of Entity Framework (EF 7 aka EF Core 1.0) no longer supports `.edmx` files.  Between the limitations with current EF 6 tooling, and complete lack of support going forward, the Database First approach with `.edmx` files seems a like a deadend.

My requirements were very simple.  I just wanted a 1:1 mapping between my database and C# Entity classes that can be updated automatically after a database change.  I don't need complex/custom mapping, inheritance, etc.  Just a simple 1:1 mapping is all I need, similar to what you would get using Linq To Sql in years past.  The solution I ended up using is **Code First From Database** along with a T4 template that allows you to customize the code generation, and automatically regenerate all of the code after a database change.  If your requirements are simple like mine, I would highly recommend the following:

"EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator"

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838
https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator

The Visual Studio Gallery link has a video that shows how it works.  Very simple, and allows for a fully automated Database First approach that I was seeking.

#### ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0

In terms of integrating this with ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0 (aka ASP.NET 5 MVC 6), the easiest approach I've found is to create a regular class library that contains your EF 6 code (e.g., Database First, or Code First from Database using T4 template mentioned above).  Then, reference your class library in your ASP.NET project.  When I did this, I was targeting the full framework only (not Core), so I modified my `project.json` file in the ASP.NET project to set the frameworks as follows:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx46"
}
```

I built my class library against the full 4.6 framework and included a reference to EF 6.1.3.  Then, I used **Add Reference** in the ASP.NET project to reference the class library project (`.csproj`) (both projects are in a single `.sln` file).  After adding the `.csproj` reference, Visual Studio was generating a warning about a version mismatch for Entity Framework (`NU1007: Dependency specified was EntityFramework >= 6.1.3 but ended up with EntityFramework 1.0.0`).  I believe this is a bug in Visual Studio 2015; you can resolve the problem by editing the `project.json` file that was automatically generated by Visual Studio as part of the Add Reference operation.  If you look in the root folder of your solution, you should see a folder named `wrap`.  Inside the `wrap` folder, you'll find subfolders for your class library and any dependencies (including Entity Framework).  The `EntityFramework` subfolder contains a `project.json` file that looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../Data/packages/EntityFramework.6.1.3/lib/net45/EntityFramework.dll"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you edit the `version` and change it to "6.1.3-*" then reload your ASP.NET project, the NU1007 warning will disappear.  More details here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/374#issuecomment-196664962

Comment: Awesome write-up. The file within EntityFramework in my wrap folder is "project.json" not "package.json". Don't forget to restart VS when you change the target version. Horrible bug this...